# mlr / FSelector install error...java related

Tags: java, r

I have been banging my head on this one for a day or two.  Trying to run some analysis through 'mlr' and I'm getting stuck on a package install error.  Specifically, I am trying to run:

```
im_feat <- generateFilterValuesData(trainTask, method = c("information.gain","chi.squared"))
```

My initial run of this code generated the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘FSelector’
```

Smart guy that I am, I decided to install FSelector.  However, when I did...it would bomb when it tried to load the dependency 'RWeka'.  Specially, I got the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWeka', details: 
call: .jnew("weka.core.WekaPackageManager")
error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:weka/core/WekaPackageManager : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

I have been digging on this for a day or so.  Here are the things I've already done:

- Updated java...runtime and DK
- Ensured both R and java were 64-bit
- Made sure JAVA_HOME was pointing to the correct place as follows:

  ```
  Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home')
  ```

Any ideas are sincerely welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Never got an answer, but I was able to fix this.  For the sake of completeness, I figured I'd post what worked for me in case anyone else has this problem and finds this question.

Step 1: Terminal

```
$ sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Step 2: Back in RStudio

```
install.packages("rJava",type = "source")
install.packages("RWeka")
```

FSelector and all related packages have been loading and working fine after this.

Comment: Great! Your tip truly saved my day.  Note that I am using Mac and the solution works well.