# Another rJava library install error: rJava.rdb' is corrupt

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am having a time with java related packages this week.  I finally got my RWeka working (see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728983/mlr-fselector-install-error-java-related/43771982#43771982)), but now I'm having rJava issues.

The package seems to load up fine, but when I load the library I get the following:

```
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava/R/rJava.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the package cannot be decompressed by R, then this error has occurred.

### Suggestion#1:

1. Try restarting R and running the app again.
2. Sometimes for creation time of .rdb, may some issue occured.

Resource Link: [Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424608/error-in-fetchkey-lazy-load-database)

### Suggestion#2: Quit and restart a clean R session from within R?

If you're in RStudio: command/ctrl + shift + F10

You can also use

`.rs.restartR()`

Resource Link: [Quit and restart a clean R session from within R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r)

### Suggestion#3:

Use a newer version of devtools, It may solve your issue sometimes.

Resource Link: https://github.com/wch/movies/issues/3

### Suggestion#4:

Check your `JAVA_HOME` is correctly set or not.

Use the followings one:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='...path to JRE...')
```

OR,

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_51\\jre')
```

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667945/2293534

Comment: Suggestion#4 is works for me. Set the path and restart the RGui.exe.

Answer (score 3):

You should restart R after re-installing `rJava.rdb`. see below Stackoverflow link as this is a similar problem

[Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424608/error-in-fetchkey-lazy-load-database)

Comment: This worked!  I love it when the simple answer works!

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Restart R session

`.rs.restartR()`

2. Set JavaPath

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\jre')`